# SELECT FOR UPDATE vs. UPDATE, then SELECT

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb

I've created a service application that uses multi-threading for parallel processing of data located in an InnoDB table (about 2-3 millions of records, and no more InnoDB-related queries performed by the application). Each thread makes the following queries to the mentioned table:

1. START TRANSACTION
2. SELECT FOR UPDATE (SELECT pk FROM table WHERE status='new' LIMIT 100 FOR UPDATE)
3. UPDATE (UPDATE table SET status='locked' WHERE pk BETWEEN X AND Y)
4. COMMIT
5. DELETE (DELETE FROM table WHERE pk BETWEEN X AND Y)

The guys from forum.percona.com gave me a piece of advice - do not use SELECT FOR UPDATE and UPDATE because of longer time needed for transaction to execute (2 queries), and waiting lock timeouts that result. Their advice was (autocommit is on):

1. UPDATE (UPDATE table SET status='locked', thread = Z LIMIT 100)
2. SELECT (SELECT pk FROM table WHERE thread = Z)
3. DELETE (DELETE FROM table WHERE pk BETWEEN X AND Y)

and it was supposed to improve performance. However, instead, I got even more deadlocks and wait lock timeouts than before...

I read a lot about optimizing InnoDB, and tuned the server correspondlingly, so my InnoDB settings are 99% ok. This fact is also proven by the first scenario working fine and better than second one. The my.cnf file:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 512M
innodb_thread_concurrency = 16
innodb_thread_sleep_delay = 0
innodb_log_buffer_size = 4M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
```

Any ideas why the optimization had no success?

Comment: Can you please give example Select and Update queries? it makes a big difference if you are accessing rows by primary key, or using a range index - locking the gaps.

Comment: Well. Guess where *I'm* not going for advice...

Comment: Added real queries to topic, please take a look

Answer (score 3):

What I understand from the description of your process is:

1. You have a table which has many rows that needs to be processed.
2. You select a row from that table (using for update) so that other threads cannot get         access to the same row.
3. When you are done you update the row and commit the transaction.
4. And then delete the row from the database.

If this is the case then you are doing the right thing as this will have less locks then the second approach you mentioned.

You can decrease the lock contention further by removing the delete statement as this will lock the whole table. Rather than doing that add a flag (new column named processed) and update that. And delete the rows at the end when all the threads are done processing.

You can also make the work distribution intelligent by batching the work load - in your case the row range (may be using PK) which each thread is going to process - in that case you can do a simple select and no need for the FOR UPDATE clause and it will work fast.

Comment: If this is the case then you are doing the right thing as this will have less locks then the second approach you mentioned - WHY?

Comment: in that case you can do a simple select and no need for the FOR UPDATE clause and it will work fast - I run 100+ threads that use PK ranges to determine own workload

Comment: Added real queries to the question's body